# calling gccxml from my code (Windows)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, gcc

I'm writing a tool that makes use of gccxml. Basically I'm parsing the output xml file that has been created by gccxml. This works great on my windows machine in visual studio except for a couple of drawbacks. Here's the current state  of my project:

cmake_gui gave me a visual studio solution that compiles perfectly (x64 Release). It's set up to create three executables in E:\cmake_builds\GCCXML\bin\Release.

My own C++ tool is located in a different VS solution file. When it's supposed to make use of gccxml the following code is used:

```
bool Parser::ParseFile( const std::string& _szFileName, std::string& _gccxmlPath, 
                             const std::string& _tempFileLocation,
                             std::string& _errorStr)
{
   bool retVal = true;

   printf("Parsing file %s...\n\n", _szFileName.c_str());

   /* format _gccxmlPath, adding a final forward slash to the path if required */
   char lastChar = _gccxmlPath.at(_gccxmlPath.length()-1);
   if(lastChar != '/' && lastChar != '\\')
      _gccxmlPath += "/";

   /* set up a temporary environment path variable so that the gccxml exe files may locate each other */
   char envPath[500];
   sprintf_s(envPath, "PATH=%s", _gccxmlPath.c_str());
   const char* gccxml_env[] =
   {
      /* set path to gccxml directory where all exe files from gccxml are located */
      envPath,
      0
   };

   /* path & filename of gccxml.exe */
   char gccxml_exe[500];
   sprintf_s(gccxml_exe, "%sgccxml.exe", _gccxmlPath.c_str());
   /* parameter string used to set gccxml output filename */
   char fxmlParam[500];
   sprintf_s(fxmlParam, "-fxml=\"%s\"", _tempFileLocation.c_str());


   /* synthesize argument list for gccxml*/
   /* see: http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Running.html */
   /* and: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html */
   const char* gccxml_args[GCCXML_PARAM_LEN];
   unsigned int curPos = 0;
   /* 1st argument: exe name */
   gccxml_args[curPos++] = "gccxml.exe";
   /* the source code to be compiled */
   gccxml_args[curPos++] = _szFileName.c_str();
   /* try to find out which msvc compiler to use */
   gccxml_args[curPos++] = "--gccxml-compiler cl";
   /* the output xml file */
   gccxml_args[curPos++] = fxmlParam;
   /* last argument: zero termination */
   gccxml_args[curPos++] = 0;


   /* call gccxml & compile the source code file */
   if(0 != _spawnvpe(P_WAIT, gccxml_exe, gccxml_args, gccxml_env))
   {
      _errorStr += "GCCXML Compiler Error";
      return false;
   }
   /* now parse the gccxml output file from tempfile ... */
   ...
   ...
   return retVal;
}
```

as you can see I have to set up a local environment PATH variable to make sure the three executables are able to find each other.

This works great for what I want to do.

Unfortunately I can't use this method to call gccxml.exe when I *move* the three executables to a different directory. Of course I provide the new _gccxmlPath string but gccxml returns

```
"Support item Vc10/Include is not available..."
```

telling me that it looked in the folder into which I moved the executables. All my local copies of Vc10/Include however are located somewhere totally different and I don't understand how it had been able find one of these before I moved the executables.

It seems like this problem can be fixed by calling gccxml_vcconfig.exe using the parameters "patch_dir" and providing the directory "gccxml/Source/GCC_XML/VcInstall" from my gccxml source files. I'm, however, not able to solve my issue this way using any of the spawn* commands.
If I do the gccxml_vcconfig.exe runs just fine but after that I'm trying to call gccxml.exe and it turns out that it still looks in the same directory as before.

So gccxml_vcconfig.exe was probably not what I was looking for?

I'm trying to find a way to provide my tool to users who don't want to recompile gccxml on their machine so I'd like to distribute the thre binaries (and what else is needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to let you know. I found a way of doing what I wanted to do. The trick is as follows:

right before vpe-spawning gccxml using its own location as environment (as shown above) vp-spawn the gccxml_vcconfig.exe without providing any environment path variables. This may look like this

```
     std::string VcInstallDir = resolveRelativePath(_gccxmlPath + "../share/gccxml-0.9/VcInstall");
     std::string GCCXML09Dir = resolveRelativePath(_gccxmlPath + "../share/gccxml-0.9");

     std::vector<const char*> gccxml_config_args;
     gccxml_config_args.push_back("gccxml_vcconfig.exe");
     gccxml_config_args.push_back(VcInstallDir.c_str());
     gccxml_config_args.push_back(GCCXML09Dir.c_str());
     gccxml_config_args.push_back(0);

     if(0 != _spawnvp(_P_WAIT, gccxml_vcconfig_exe.c_str(), gccxml_config_args.data()))
     {
        _errorStr += "GCCXML Configuration Error";
        return false;
     }
```

note that resolveRelativePath is a self written function for string manipulation that produces a valid absolute path; gccxml_vcconfig_exe contains the absolute path to my exe file

and I somewhat changed my coding style from arrays to std::vectors as you can see